# Merge json files in the same s3 bucket subfolder for multiple subfolders and save it in that subfolder python

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, merge, boto3

I have multiple subfolders and in each subfolder I have 2 json files in s3 bucket. For instance I have:

1. bucket_name/test/folder A/folder 2/test.json
2. bucket_name/test/folder A/folder 2/test_2.json

I would like to combine json files in these folders. But, then I also have folders such as:

3. bucket_name/test/folder B/folder 4/test.json
4. bucket_name/test/folder B/folder 4/test_2.json

and I would like to combine json files in these folders too.
I would like to merge these 2 json files within the same s3 bucket subfolder and save them in that specific subfolder. However, I cannot able to merge in each specific folder. Here is my trial:

```
def get_s3_list(bucket, prefix):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    obj_list = [lc['Key'] for lc in objects['Contents']]
    while 'NextContinuationToken' in objects:
        objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, ContinuationToken=objects['NextContinuationToken'])
        obj_list.extend([lc['Key'] for lc in objects['Contents']])
    return obj_list
 # Create a list with the content of s3 staging bucket
s3_list = get_s3_list('bucket_name', 'test')

bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
prefix = 'test'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
result = []

jsonfilesname = ['test.json', 'test_2.json']
json_list_files = []
for sub_list in s3_list:
    if sub_list.split('/')[0] == prefix:
        if sub_list.endswith('.json') or sub_list.endswith('.JSON'):
             json_list_files.append(sub_list)
for key in json_list_files:

    data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
    content = json.loads(data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8"))
    result.append(content)
```

My code fails at combining each pairs of json files within each subfolder so I only get the json files within a list.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not explained how your code is failing.

Comment: I am getting the content of each file as a list but I cannot combine each pair of json files within that specific folder and save it. thanks

Comment: You seem to reading the two JSON files and merging their content but you haven't made any attempt to write the merged content back to S3. Calculate the key that you want for the merged JSON object and use [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) to write a JSON dump of the merged data to that S3 key.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think I am okay with saving the result once I can get it. My problem is how to calculate the key for merged JSON object.